# Tomcat starts but home page cannot open -- Port incompatibility with Anaconda

Tags: tomcat, anaconda, jupyter

I'm trying to run Wolfram Mathematica on a Google Cloud instance and I am following this explanation:

[How do I install and configure webMathematica on Linux?](https://support.wolfram.com/17399#Setting%20up%20Java)

Everything was done, but here's a fact. I created the GCP instance with an image that contained a previous installation of Anaconda and Jupyter. In the beginning I suspected Jupyter had locked port 8080 but then I altered Jupyter config file. It didn't work.

Tomcat server starts but I cannot open in the GCP machine IP: 8080

I tried to change Tomcat ports in conf/server.xml and this also didn't work. I get the following error when accessing http://machine_ip:8080:

[image: Error]

Do you have any suggestions besides creating a whole new fresh instance from zero ? I also tried:

```
sudo kill $(sudo lsof -t -i:8080)
```

but it didn't work.

Also, I'm running the whole thing from the command line.

I have this inside /opt/anaconda3/share/jupyter/lab/static

[image: static]

Answer (score 0):

I guess I found the solution:

By running `sudo apt-get install tomcat8` I managed to install the environment properly in a new instance on GCP. Now I get:

[image: OK]